# Who gets Super Bowl rings?

Tags: american-football, nfl, awards

When a team wins the Super Bowl, there are a lot of players and organizational members that helped in the process. For each team playing this year, there are multiple players on injured reserve that helped the teams early on, but won't be playing for the Lombardi trophy. Who actually gets a Super Bowl ring? Are IR players like Mario Manningham (49ers) and Lardarius Webb (Ravens) eligible to receive rings? What about all of the coaches and coordinators and front-office employees?

Comment: If the team loses do they also get Super Bowl rings

Comment: The losing team does not get Super Bowl rings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Every member of the active roster
- The coaching staff
- The entire front office and ownership
- The cheerleaders get rings depending on ownership's decision. But it has been the tradition lately for cheerleaders to get rings.
- Injured Reserve and practice squad get rings if their team decides to give them out to them. Usually they do.
- Also, in some cases, players traded during the season will get them too, if they suited up and played during they regular season. This is also by ownership's decision

To sum up, the ownership pays for all the rings and decides who receives them. The list above shows the norm.

1. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_ring#Details)
2. [Source](http://www.nola.com/saints/index.ssf/2011/09/former_saint_steve_gleason_rec.html)

Answer (score -4):

I think players who get cut and may be out of the league get rings if they were on the 53 man roster for atleast 1 week. I am not 100% sure if this is required.

Comment: At Sports SE, we encourage expert, well-researched answers. Are there any sources that back up your "thoughts?"