# Has anyone been "guaranteed" a Super Bowl ring because they played for both teams during the season?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

I was reading [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2206/16092) to the question "Who gets Super Bowl rings?" which says

> Also, in some cases, players traded during the season will get them too, if they suited up and played during they regular season. This is also by ownership's decision

Was ever a time when a player was guaranteed a Super Bowl ring because they are in the final game but they started the season for their opponents team?

Answer (score 1):

A player can not be guaranteed a Super Bowl ring because the ownership makes the decision whether or not someone gets a ring if they did not play in the Super Bowl
(according to [Who gets Super Bowl rings?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/who-gets-super-bowl-rings/2206#2206)).

Comment: Replying to user16493
I think he just means played on both superbowl teams at one point during the season. I couldnt find any player who has done this sadly